# Chain rule for Radon-Nikodym derivative (without a.e.)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Assume that $\mu, \nu, \rho$ are $\sigma$-finite positive measures. If $\nu << \mu, \rho << \nu$, then $\rho << \mu$ and $$\frac{d\rho}{d\mu} = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}.$$ ($\nu << \mu$ := $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu.$)

Proof It is clear that $\rho << \nu.$ By applying Radon-Nikodym decomposition to $\nu << \mu, \rho << \nu, \rho << \mu,$ we have $$d\nu = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu, d\rho = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}d\nu, d\rho = \frac{d\rho}{d\mu}d\mu.$$ Then I conclude that $$d\rho = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$$ which says that $$\rho(A) = \int_A \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} d\mu := \int_A fg d\mu.$$ By $\rho << \mu$, $$d\rho = h d\mu$$ for some non-negative measurable function $h$. So $$\rho(A) = \int_A h d\mu.$$
This yields that $$0 = \rho(A) - \rho(A) = \int_A fg -h d\mu \ (\mbox{Here I am not sure if} \ \rho(A) - \rho(A) \neq \infty - \infty) $$ for any measurable set $A$ which yields that $$\frac{d\rho}{d\mu} = h = fg = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\ \mbox{a.e.}.$$ I do not know how to move from here to conclude $$\frac{d\rho}{d\mu} = h = fg = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$$ and I am not sure if my proof works (e.g. at $\rho(A) - \rho(A) = \infty - \infty).$ Any suggestion please ?

Comment: You can conclude that $0=\rho(A)-\rho(A)$  for any $A$ such that that $\rho(A)<+\infty$.  So you have that $\int_A fg d\mu = \int_A h d\mu$,    for any $A$ such that that $\rho(A)<+\infty$. Then use the fact that $\rho$ is $\sigma$-finite and conclude that $\int_A fg d\mu = \int_A h d\mu$,    for any $A$.

Comment: Radon-Nykodym derivatives are unique  only up to $=$ a.e..  
So, once you proved $$\frac{d\rho}{d\mu} = h = fg = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\ [\mu]\mbox{a.e.}$$ 
you have proved $$\frac{d\rho}{d\mu} = h = fg = \frac{d\rho}{d\nu}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$$ That is all.

Comment: @Ramiro Can you point out a bit more why $\sigma$-finiteness of $\rho$ give that the integral holds for any measurable set.

Comment: Sure. Let the measurable space under consideration be $(X, \mathscr{A})$. Since $\rho$ is $\sigma$-finite, for any set $A\in \mathscr{A}$, there are sets $A_n\in \mathscr{A}$, such that $\rho(A_n)<+\infty$ and 
$$ A= \sum_{n} A_n$$
You have already proved that, for each $n$, since $\rho(A_n)<+\infty$, 
$$ \int_{A_n} fgd\mu = \int_{A_n} hd\mu$$ 
So we have 
$$\int_A fgd\mu = \sum_{n} \int_{A_n} fgd\mu = \sum_{n} \int_{A_n} hd\mu = \int_A hd\mu$$ 
Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: @Ramiro Precisely, do $\rho$ is $\sigma$-finite means there exist $A_n$ such that $$X = \cup A_n$$ and $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ ?. Then for any measurable set $B$, set $B_n = B \cap A_n$, the existence of $A_n$ in your explanation above is my $B_n$, right ? Then you use Monotone convergence to $f_n = fg1_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i }$ to have the last equality. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: 1. In your comment above when you wrote $\mu(A_n)<\infty$, i think you meant $\rho(A_n)<\infty$. Right?  (we are talking about $\rho$ being $\sigma$-finite). 

2. Assuming your answer is yes to item 1, then my answer is yes. There are equivalents ways to define $\sigma$-finiteness.  Yours is one of them.  And yes, to prove in detail de last equality, we use the Monotone Convergence Theorem as you said (and the fact that $fg,h \geq 0$ $[\mu]$ a.e.). Your understanding is correct.

Comment: @Ramiro Yeah, $\rho$ not $\mu$. Thank you very much for your help.